# How to retrieve a newly created google sheet using nodejs and google sheets api

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

I am working with the google sheets API and I created a new google sheet from the google sheet API using node js. When the new sheet is created, I console logged the response and when I click the spreadsheetUrl, it ask for permission from service account.Then, I found it is created on the service account email but, how would I login through service account email in google and view the newly created google sheet? How do I retrieve that newly created spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You created new Spreadsheet using the Service account.
- You want to retrieve and view the created Spreadsheet.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Issue:

When the Spreadsheet is created by the Service account, the owner of Spreadsheet is the email of Service account. So when you log in to your own Google Drive, the Spreadsheet cannot be seen because the Service account is different account from yours. And also, there is no Web interface for the Service account. So the log in cannot be done with the Service account.

#### Solution:

In order to see the created Spreadsheet in your Google Drive and your account, please share your account with the Spreadsheet created by [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) with the Service account. In this case, please add the permissions (writer, reader, owner and so on) for your account to the created Spreadsheet with the Service account. By this, you can see it at your Google Drive, and also retrieve it using your account.

#### References:

- [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.